# Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I have a mysql 8 server with the caching_sha2_password option, I installed Connector/C in x32 but when I try to connect I get this message from erro:

Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module is not found.
[2059]

My code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include <iostream>

static char *host = "127.0.0.1";
static char *user = "arthurdent";
static char *pass ="42";
static char *dbname ="gestion_test";

unsigned int port = 3307;
static char *unix_socket = NULL;
unsigned int flag = 0;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    MYSQL  *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP,"client");

    if(!(mysql_real_connect(conn,host,user,pass,dbname,port,unix_socket,flag))){
        
        printf("\nError: %s [%d]\n",mysql_error(conn),mysql_errno(conn));
            char c ;
        {
        c = getchar() ;
        }
        while ( c != '\n' ) ;
        return 1;
        }
    
    printf("Connection Succesful ! \n\n"); 

    
    res = mysql_store_result(conn);

    while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res)){
        
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",row[0],row[1],row[2]);
        }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(conn);

    char c ;
        {
        c = getchar() ;
        }
        while ( c != '\n' ) ;
    


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `char c ;` must be `int c ;`.

Comment: This does not do what you think: `while ( c != '\n' ) ;`. you might try to add a `do` before the block.